# jQuery autocomplete and flask

Tags: jquery, python, json, autocomplete, flask

Greetings Stackoverflow,

I am struggling to get the correct information from my JSON object I have passed to the input field.

## Form

```
   class ClassForm(Form):
        function_name = StringField('Students', validators = [Required()])
        submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

## Controller

### index

This is the controller, which just passes the ClassForm to the view, which will populate all the fields

```
@admin.route('/')
def index():
    form = ClassForm()
    return render_template('admin/class/index.html', form=form)
```

### autocomplete

This is the get request, which will get all the first-names, last-names and id from the User table(also filtering it with roles, but this is irrelevant)

```
@admin.route('/autocomplete',methods=['GET'])
def autocomplete():
    u = UserClass()
    d = ['aa', 'bb', 'test', 'long name with space', 'test2', 'mega test']
    for x in u.getAllStudents():
        d.append({'Firstname': x[0], 'Lastname': x[1], 'ID': x[2]})
```

this is btw getAllStudents()

```
db.session.query(User.user_fistName, User.user_lastName, User.id).filter(Role.role_name.in_(['Student'])).join(Role).all()
```

Well as you can see I am passing a normal list just to see if it works with that.

## View

I have my normal jinja view where I am passing all the information to the view.

```
{{form.function_name.label()}}
{{form.function_name()}}
```

### javascript call

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '{{ url_for("admin.autocomplete") }}'
        }).done(function (data) {
            $('#function_name').autocomplete({
                source: data.json_list,
                datatype: "json",
                datafields: [
                        { name: 'Firstname' },
                        { name: 'Lastname'},
                        {name: 'ID'}
                    ]
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

if I try to type a name I have in the database, it **will not** autosuggest it, but if I try one of the names I have in the list (variable NAMES), they are appended correct and it can auto-suggest them. Also if I look at ***autocomplete?term*** I can see that I am indeed getting the correct information, but that it generates it as a MultiDimensional list as you can see:

### populated JSON list

```
{
  "json_list": [
    "aa",
    "bb",
    "test",
    "long name with space",
    "test2",
    "mega test",
    {
      "Firstname": "John",
      "ID": 1,
      "Lastname": "Doe"
    },
    {
      "Firstname": "Jane",
      "ID": 2,
      "Lastname": "Doe"
    }
  ]
}
```

So I am wondering, how is it possible to auto-suggest the names in the multiarray list with dictionary variable names(key values)? 
And after that on a button next to it, add to list? Where the values will append to the selected area. For example Firstname and lastname will be merged into one string and the keyvalue with ID will be used be printed in the link?

```
<ol>
  <li>John Doe<a href="ID?=1"></a></li>
  <li>John Doe<a href="ID?=2"></a></li>
  <li>John Doe<a href="ID?=3"></a></li>
</ol>
```

***edit, added dictionary key values to the json object***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '{{ url_for("admin.autocomplete") }}'
    }).done(function (data) {

     var newData = [];

     for (var i = 0; i < data.json_list.length; i++) {

      var obj = {
       label: data.json_list[i].Firstname + ' ' + data.json_list[i].Lastname,
       value: data.json_list[i].Firstname + ' ' + data.json_list[i].Lastname,
       id: data.json_list[i].ID
      }

      newData.push(obj);
     };


        $('#function_name').autocomplete({
            source: newData,
            datatype: "json"
        });
    });
```